# Facebook application: fb and twitter share counts on user by user basis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I'm creating a Facebook application, in this app users can choose photos from their fb galleries or upload from their desktop and some image processing will be done on them. The view of the images will be changed. Users are able to share the images via facebook and twitter.

I need to have the statistics of the shared images on user basis.

If to describe it in table basis, it'd have looked like this:

**sid(share id) | uid(user id) | count(number of shares) | img (image name) | link(view page)**

I'm going to group the users by their location, and show the sharing(fb, twitter) statistics in google maps.

Right now I can detect the total number of shares of the image, through the link(url). But I can't count the user's shares.

Number of clicks can be be detected on the client side, but it's not possible to detect if the link is share successfully or not.

Any help is appreciated a lot.